# Convex optimization of a convolution problem

Tags: convolution, signal-processing

I want to optimize a sparse problem using discrete math of the following form:

S [16500x1]: measured data vector

D [1500x2]: a dictionary matrix containing two basis signals of 1500 samples

X [16500x2]: the impulse responses of the problem that need to be found.

The signal generation has the following structure:
$$S[n] = \sum_i D_i[n] * X_i[n] + \eta$$
So basically, the signal S[n] is the sum of discrete convolutions of $D_i$ and $X_i$.

To reconstruct the impulse responses $X_i$ from a measurement of $S$ I use a sparse, convex optimization problem with following loss function:
$$ \epsilon = |\sum_i D_i * X_i - S |^2_2 + \lambda \cdot |X|_1^1$$

I want to solve this using simple gradient descent, so I calculate the gradient of $\epsilon$:

$$\frac{\partial \epsilon[n]}{\partial X} = 2\cdot (\sum_i D_i * X_i - S) * D_i + \lambda\cdot sign(X)$$

However, when I implement this, the loss diverges, even with very small step sizes. Only when I flip the second $D_i$ used in the second convolution (in the time dimension), I get the results I am expecting. The idea for reversing came from an implementation I saw of this in the frequency domain, where the hermetian transpose was used in the multiplication (which equates to time reversal in time domain).

So a long introduction for the question: why do I need to time-reverse the second $D_i$ (right before the plus sign)? I do not see where this is comming from, based on my knowledge on chain rules. Any help would be greatly appreciated in understanding this!

Thanks!
PS. Sorry for sloppy notation. Not a mathematician.

EDIT: added the code:

```
gradientVecs = zeros(size(X));
maxIter = 1000;
for cntIter = 1 : maxIter
    curDX = 0;
    for cntDict = 1 : size( D, 2 )
        curDX = curDX + conv( X( :, cntDict ), (D(:, cntDict)),  'same' );
    end
    curLoss = sum( sum( ( curDX - S ).^2 ) ) + lambda * sum( sum( abs( X ) ) );

    for cntDict = 1:size(D, 2)
        % Why is there a flip here????                   HERE???     
        gradientVecs(:, cntDict) = 2 * conv( (curDX - S), flip(D(:, cntDict)), 'same') + lambda * sign (X(:, cntDict)); 
    end

    X = X - 0.02*( gradientVecs ) ;

end
```

Comment: Which convolution are you using?

Comment: conv() of matlab. I added the code to the original post

Comment: When you convolve a sequence of length $m$ with a sequence of length $n$, you should get a sequence of length $m + n - 1$

Comment: Correct, but I use the 'same' argument which keeps the size of the output same to the first input.

Comment: Why are you truncating the output?

Comment: Because it makes sense for the physical signal I am interested in reconstructing, and it makes everything a bit cleaner in terms of subsequent steps in the processing chain.

Comment: Why not add the columns?  Aren't you adding the convolutions?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/43670/21075)

Comment: CVXPY has [`conv`](https://www.cvxpy.org/api_reference/cvxpy.atoms.affine.html#conv).  Perhaps CVX has something similar.  Implementing your own numerical algorithms is dangerous

Comment: While I do appreciate all the replies so far, they are besides the main point of my question. I am not implementing a convolution operator, I am trying to solve a gradient descent problem, and I do not understand why the partial derivative of a convolution needs the time reversal of one of the convolution operands to be correct:

d/dx( f( a*x ) ), with * being the convolution: $f'(a * x)*a(-t)$

Comment: Partial derivative?  What makes you think the objective is differentiable?

Comment: Because why wouldnt the square of a convolution not be differentiable?

Comment: Doesn't your loss function have a 1-norm?

Comment: Yes. But again, that is not the core of my question. The question remains the same even if the l1 part is not there.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the answer to my own question:

First, let us recap the problem we want to find the gradient for:

$$\epsilon = | \sum_i d_i*x_i |_2^2 + \lambda \cdot \sum_i |x_i|_1$$

We can rewrite the discrete convolution operator in matrix form:
$$\sum_i d_i*x_i = \sum_i D_i \cdot x_i$$
where $D_i$ is a matrix of which the columns are shifted versions of $d_i$. $D_i$ therefore is a Toeplitz matrix.

then, we can rewrite the loss function:
$$\epsilon = | \sum_i D_i \cdot x_i |_2^2 + \lambda \cdot \sum_i |x_i|_1$$

We can then write out the $L_2$ norm:
$$ \epsilon = (  \sum_i D_i \cdot x_i )^T\cdot(  \sum_i D_i \cdot x_i ) + \lambda \cdot \sum_i |x_i|_1$$

Which simplifies to:
$$ \epsilon = \sum_i D_i^T x_i^T x_i D_i - 2s^T\sum_i D_i x_i + s^Ts  + \lambda \cdot \sum_i |x_i|_1$$

We can then take the gradient w.r.t $x_i$, dropping the sum over $i$:
$$ \frac{\partial \epsilon}{\partial x_i} = 2D^T_iD_ix_i - 2D_i^Ts + \lambda \cdot sign(x_i)$$

$$ \frac{\partial \epsilon}{\partial x_i} = 2\cdot D^T \cdot(D_i x_i -s) + \lambda \cdot sign(x_i)$$

The multiplication with $D^T$ before the $(D_i x_i -s)$ equals to a convolution with the time inverse of $d_i$ because of the Toeplitz structure of $D_i$

Comment: This is almost true! I think that this implementation is correct only if the impulse response is odd-length (which is not in your case)

Comment: Could you elaborate? It does work with even-length IRs in practice.

Comment: If $D(h)$ is the convolution matrix associated with filter $h$, then the matrix-vector product Dx is equal to conv(x,h,'same'). Now if you implement the matrix-vector product $D^Ty$ as a convolution, it is equal to conv(y,flip(h),'same') only in the odd-length case. I suggest you to make tests in the even-length case to convince yourself of this.